# PHPUnit and Selenium: setUpBeforeClass() not called

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I want to use setUpBeforeClass() to setup a db connection, and do some logging, but it is not being called before my tests execute (or at all, for that matter).
I have the following:

```
class TestSetup extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase {
    public static function setUpBeforeClass() {
        //do some setup stuff here for all my tests
    }
    protected function setUp() {
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://' . $this->deviceIp);
    }
    protected function testOne() {
        //do a test here
    }
    protected function testTwo() {
        //do a test here
    }
}
```

I did some digging into PHPUnit/Frameworks/TestSuite.php and have confirmed that on line 660 that $this->testCase is bool(false).  But I couldn't figure out if it should be true or where that should happen (other than in __construct()).

I'm slightly over my head here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let me know if I can provide any other helpful information.

Josh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the docs but the code seems to agree with you.

In `PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php` run method (line 289+) there is no sign of calling setUpBeforeClass (or any other method that might do so).

If you consider that an issue I'd suggest opening a ticket on [`phpunits issue tracker`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues).

For a workaround you could use a static property in `setUp` like this:

```
protected function setUp() {
    static $db = null;
    if($db === null) {
        $db = whatevery_you_do_there();
    }
    $this->db = $db;
}
```

that should work, sort of, as if you'd run it in `setUpBeforeClass()`

Comment: Thank you, twofold.  First, for confirming that I wasn't missing something :).  Second, for a very clever solution that does exactly what I need.